# MySQL - Issue with SELECT & GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, group-concat

Hello the wonderful community,

I have a basic config MySQL / PHP with this DB :

- Pages Table
- Tags Table
- Pages_Tags Table

Query :

```
SELECT *, GROUP_CONCAT('tags_name')
FROM pages 
LEFT JOIN pages_tags ON pages_tags.pages_id = pages.pages_id
LEFT JOIN tags ON tags.tags_id = pages_tags.tags_id 
GROUP BY pages_tags.pages_id;
```

and i have the following error :

```
"Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains
 nonaggregated column this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by"
```

So i made a lot of researches, and seems there are 2 solutions :

1/ To change the SQL mode
2/ To have the same column in the SELECT & GROUP BY.

Both seems bad solutions. The first because i don't want to change the default config and the second is insane, i need a lot of columns in the SELECT and not only the GROUP BY. Especially if the query is more complicated with a lot more LEFT JOIN. I need to display all theses infos.

Do you have any solutions ? Alternative with other methods ? 
I'm open to anything ;)

Thanks a lot !!

Comment: show us some sample data

Comment: Sample data of what ? 
It's a basic structure : Pages Table with hundred columns, Tags Table with few columns and a joint table to connect both cause a page can be linked to multiple tags. 
I need to have a list of the pages with all the tags linked listed in one field.

Answer (score 0):

starting from mysql 5.7 you can use column in select not involved  in aggreagtion function and not mentioned in group by clause, so you should not use * (all) for column but add explict column name in select and mention the column in select not involved  in aggregation function in group by

```
    SELECT `pages_tags`.`pages_id`, GROUP_CONCAT('tags_name')
    FROM `pages` 
    LEFT JOIN `pages_tags` ON `pages_tags`.`pages_id` = `pages`.`pages_id` 
    LEFT JOIN `tags` ON `tags`.`tags_id` = `pages_tags`.`tags_id` 
    GROUP BY `pages_tags`.`pages_id`
```

Comment: Thanks ! But it doesn't help me. Because like i said at the end of my post, i need more informations than that. I need all the table columns. It's why i wrote "SELECT *" so how i can do ?

Comment: Then update  your question and add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: The expected result is simple : i want all the datas ! 
Not just "`pages_tags`.`pages_id`, GROUP_CONCAT('tags_name')", i need "*, GROUP_CONCAT('tags_name')"
And i'm looking for a solution to get all the data. I need all the columns of the PAGES table.

Comment: You have post a question for an error and with my answer  the error si not more present .. so i think my answer is the right solution at your problem "Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains
 nonaggregated column this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by". Due the fact that we don't know your data struct and what you really need if someone ask for better explain  i think you should answer  addinng the info requested .. not avoind to do.   Otherwise we can't produce  valid  suggestion

Comment: I posted my question with the indication of the cause and how to fix it. So i know it already. But i said both solutions don't match with my need because i can't have only the same columns in the GROUP BY and in the SELECT. 
Whatever my data structure is, the question is still : how to have MORE fields that the one in the GROUP_BY.
My structure is basic : 2 tables and a joint table. It's a basic structure. And my expectation is to get ALL the columns. 
So is there a solution with the GROUP_CONCAT & GROUP_BY or is there an alternative with other MySQL method ?